# FFmpeg RTSP problem with IP camera

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

I download FFmpeg windows binary and use ffplay.exe successfully for media files and some Ip Cameras with RTSP support (eg Acti).

I try ffplay on  a Bosch( h264) NDC  265 P camera it does not work. When i start ffplay with debug option i get folllowing

```
D:\Test>ffplay -debug 1 rtsp:/XXXXXXXXXX/video
FFplay version SVN-r26400, Copyright (c) 2003-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 18 2011 04:09:28 with gcc 4.4.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libgsm --enable-libvorb
is --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg
 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb
--enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --arch=x86 --enable-runtime-cpudetect -
-enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lpolarss
l -lws2_32 -lwinmm' --target-os=mingw32 --enable-avisynth --enable-w32threads --
cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='ccache i686-mingw32-gcc' --enable-memalign-hack
 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
[rtsp @ 006db540] SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 XXXXXXXXXX
s=LIVE VIEW
t=0 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 35
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=control:rtsp://XXXXXXXXXX/video
a=recvonly
a=fmtp:35 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0028;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00A
KI2NKAoAt2AgEA==,aO48gA==

[rtsp @ 006db540] video codec set to: (null)
[rtsp @ 006db540] hello state=0
[rtsp @ 006db540] Probe buffer size limit 5000000 reached
[rtsp @ 006db540] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp:/XXXXXXXXXX/video':
  Metadata:
    title           : LIVE VIEW
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0, 4035, 1/90000: Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 90k tbr, 90k tbn,
90k tbc
rtsp:/XXXXXXXXXX/video: c1o3u0l1d7 3n2o1t5 2o.p2e1n  Ac-oVd:e c s0
.000 s:0.0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

I can play Bosch IP camera with VLC Player...But can not with FFmpeg...

So

- Does ffmpeg  not support H264?

Comment: Of course FFMPEG does support H.264, is that the only debug output that you can see?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue with H.264 stream from Bosch DINION HD camera on attempt to play it with ffplay (version 0.10).

The root cause of your problem is in the incorrect payload type in SDP:

```
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 35
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
```

Looks like that's common case for Bosch devices to send out their data on `pt` value 35 instead of the normal dynamic range.
Just remove the `pt` in the h264/mpeg4 and h263 (de)payloaders and you will have support for Bosch.

As well several related issues for this problem:

- [Bug 621296 - Bosch H263: RTSP source sends pt value 36; breaks with rtph263pdepay (caps mismatch)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=621296)
- [Bug 639292 - remove pt value from selected rtp pay/depayloaders](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=639292)

Same was found for set of another Bosch devices: Bosch DINION HD 720p IVA, Bosch DINION NBN-498-P IVA, Bosch NTC-255-PI, Bosch VIP X1600 XFM4.

Comment: I am still getting this error on these cameras today – how exactly do you remove the `pt`

Comment: @AddoSolutions, unfortunately (but luckily for me), nine years later, I am far away from these activities, codebase and appliances. Moreover the fix was not on my side so I guess the info above was the maximum I had at that moment.